# Apache JMeter Counting Number of User HTTP-Response 200 & 404

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

I am new using the Apache JMeter, I am currently using JMeter for stress test to load balancer. There are 2 Web Server pointing to the single database server. All the configuration load balancer was successfully configure and work fine. After using the JMeter, i able to create a different scenario, i.e shutdown one of the web server or removing the index file. JMeter also working fine display all the request and result each request either the thread (user) getting 404 or 200. Any idea on how to create and configure so that JMeter will display and count each the result, i.e How many number getting HTTP-response code 404 or 200 ? It possible to generate the result and transform it into the graph using the JMeter ?

```
Configuration:
Server
-Thread Group (50 Sample)
 -HTTP Request
  -Regular Expression Extractor (disabled)
  -Response Assertion (disabled)
  -View Result Tree
 -Debug Sampler (disabled)
 -Graph Results
 -Summary Report
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate [JMeter dasboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which include Errors summary:

[image]

You can create dashboard using existing log file:

> ```
> jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>
> ```

Comment: Thankkkk Youu  So Much !! solve my problem, generate log file, then transform into dashboard. Veryyy Good Solutionn !

Answer (score 2):

You do have the results already

1. Remove all the listeners from your Test Plan, the [listeners don't add any value and just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/)
2. Run your JMeter test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```
3. Open the `result.csv` file with [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) or [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or equivalent - you will have `timeStamp` and `responseCode` columns which will allow you to build some form of "Response code over time" chart

   [image]

---

Another option is using [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/#Response-Codes-per-Second) chart:

[image]

It is not a part of JMeter distribution bundle, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

---

And finally you can store the status code of the response into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

[image]

once done you can add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables):

```
sample_variables=statusCode
```

and [plot this custom variable to the HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)

Comment: Thank your for your advise sir :)